# How to configure G-WAN to use php-fpm?

Tags: php, g-wan

As title said, how to configure G-WAN to use php-fpm?

Currently using lighttpd with php-fpm. Heard G-WAN maybe even lighter, want to give it a try. But after downloading the package and have it running, doesn't seems to be able to find any doc about php-fpm setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have G-WAN support `FastCGI` you would have to write a G-WAN `handler`. We did not do that because `FastCGI` is a much slower interface than the *language runtime* loaded in the G-WAN *process address space*.

G-WAN currently supports `PH7` (multicore, loaded as a module, like `Java`,  `C#`, `C++`, or `Objective-C`) and our efforts to use Zend `PHP` as a module failed: this PHP runtime crashes once two G-WAN threads calls it.

Comment: Thx for the answer. I did more research since I post the question and your answer is expected. For my case, the web servers, no matter it is apache, lighttpd or g-wan, are just https handler, so the thinner/lighter/efficient the better. But php-fpm support is a must. The php-cli approach in g-wan benchmark test is just not acceptable.

Comment: As explained, *php-cli* is the only way for G-WAN to use the Zend PHP runtime as it crashes in a multithreaded application, like G-WAN.

Comment: We know about the threading issue with PHP. But on the other hand, we are not using threading in our php code. It is gwan choice of not implamanting a fast-cgi interface, while the current solution (php-cli) is not acceptable. We did some simple test, the gwan website benchmark result is actually showing in how fast php-cli can be invoke and shutdown by the OS, not php performance.

Comment: G-WAN can use PHP as a loaded module (rather than as CGI) IF you are NOT using threads, which you say you are doing. The code to do so has been published on Stackoverflow.