# G-Wan v 7.12.2 how to `completely remove the "Server: G-WAN"` and more

Tags: php, g-wan

I've downloaded the latest [G-WAN](http://gwan.com/). I installed and ran successfully ph7.

1. How (what var should I use) if I don't want to reveal the server's identity?
2. I couldn't find LG_PH7 in the gwan.h file, is it the `LG_PLI`?
3. With the old version (4.x) I had a .c file in handlers helping me modify default language + query_char. This file now seems to get parsed (error on start if there is a mistake), but gwan doesn't seem to comply with it, e.g. default_char is still the default ?

Thank you

Comment: Did you follow the upgrade procedure described [here](http://gwan.com/en_timeline.html), or did you instead place your servlet and handler code in a fresh installation of v7.x?  Not sure if this makes a difference (haven't upgraded yet myself), but much as I like G-WAN, it can be . . . _interesting_.

Comment: Yes, kind of upgraded according to the procedure. I have upgraded from 4.x so must have missed the 'init.c_' (and main.c_) files which answers questions number 1. and 3.

Comment: I just now looked more closely at Q2.  No, _LG_PLI_ is not the droid you are looking for.  I believe that is used to indicate the PL/I (aka [Programming Language One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/I)) language.  Might be useful when porting some 1960's-vintage code from an IBM mainframe, or maybe someone at TrustLeap added PL/I just because they could?  Anyway, I haven't used PHP (or PH7) with G-WAN.  Not sure off hand how to answer Q2 in the list.

Comment: There is a procedure for PH7 setup outlined near the bottom of [Setup of Programming Languages](http://gwan.com/faq#languages).  Maybe worth a look.  Strange that LG_PH7 got dropped from the enum in gwan.h though - maybe PH7 support got dropped?  (At least PL/I is still supported! :D  )  As recently as a month ago, Gil (a noteworthy G-WAN authority here on SO) talked about [G-WAN PH7 support in the present tense](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34162096/1404066).  If you have a support agreement with TrustLeap, you should ask them for an answer and/or patch.

Comment: Thank you , Bro, PH7 is running, however making it the default language is the issue.

Comment: One more thing. Using the default init.c file with the latest public build the query_char change does not seem to work either.

Comment: I realize you had/have PH7 running; just pointing out the setup info in case re-doing the setup after upgrading G-WAN might help.  I'm out of ideas on the PH7 issue (Q2) at this point.  On the query_char issue (Q3), you could work around that by adding URL rewrite code in a handler.  It is easy enough to do, but "feels" like a lot of work when a simple value changed on one line of code SHOULD change the query character.  Really need Gil or someone from TrustLeap to help out here.

Answer (score 0):

> the query_char change does not seem to work

This is because the `gwan/include` files do not match the executable. This is confirmed by the missing PH7 enum value and 'default language' issue.

G-WAN v7 lets you change these options from your maintenance script, handler scripts, servlet scripts as well from the `init.c` script (found in the gwan root folder).

This script also lets you remove the G-WAN banner.

We have updated the download archive with the latest include files but you should also make sure that you are not using old `gwan/include` files from your previous version.

Thanks for Sasho and Bro.Ken for their prompt assistance.